# LNK2038 problem using a static library with an executable using many dynamic dlls

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a package with static library, I am using that package to build another static library to be consumed by an executable that uses many other dlls. Hence I am building my static library with "runtime library" set to MD. The library builds fine in release/x64 but build for executable fails with LINK 20238.
When I use "dumpbin /all foo.obj >foo.txt" to check what is actually going into my obj files and look for "Linker Directives" in that output it says MT_SaticRelease. Please see below.

I cannot use MT to build my execuatble using the static library as it uses other dynamic libraries.

Comment: At StackOverflow its necessary to always add the exact text of the error message as text. No pictures of text please. In Visual Studio the Output Tab has a compile log which has the text in a convenient text format which should be easy to copy and paste to the question.

Comment: As for the runtime. All libraries must be compiled to use the same exact runtime.

Comment: you can't mix runtimes in a single executable, you can have different runtimes in each dll but you have to be careful when passing objects between the runtimes

Comment: Is there any update? Was your problem solved?

Comment: I am using all libraries with the same runtime library setting that is "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)". The package that I am using has xxx.lib for both Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) and Multi-threaded DLL (/MT) and I am using the xxx.lib for Multi-threaded DLL (/MD). So it should all work but it does not. If I build my yyy.lib w/o this package everything works and I do not see the issue. Is it possible that something is not correct with xxx.lib in the package built with Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)?

Comment: I tested static lib with /MD but cannot reproduce your problem. Can you provide    a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi, glad to know your problem has been solved! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the package. The xxx.targets file was missing the multithreadedDLL build configuration. After the package xxx.targets was fixed the issue got resolved.